# ExtJs 3.4 :NS_ERROR_MALFORMED_URI:u.conn.open(w, t, true);

Tags: ajax, servlets, extjs

I am calling Ext Ajax request when select a combo value. here is my attempt.

```
listeners: {
    select: function () {
        var selVehicleCode = Ext.getCmp('vehicleCombo').getValue();
        var selFromDate = Ext.getCmp('fromDateCombo').getValue();
        alert(selVehicleCode + " " + selFromDate);

        Ext.Ajax.request({
            method: 'GET',
            loadMask: true,
            scope: this,
            url: "http://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + projectName + "/" + "SetDefaultValues",
            success: function (response, request) {
                //Ext.MessageBox.alert('success', response.responseText);
                var jsonData = Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
                console.log(jsonData);
                for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.defaultVal.length; i++) {
                    var _category = String(jsonData.defaultVal[i].category);
                    if (_category == 1) {
                        Ext.getCmp('drivercombo').setValue(String(jsonData.defaultVal[i].name));
                    }
                    if (_category == 2) {
                        Ext.getCmp('porter1combo').setValue(String(jsonData.defaultVal[i].name));
                    }
                    if (_category == 3) {
                        Ext.getCmp('porter2combo').setValue(String(jsonData.defaultVal[i].name));
                    }
                    if (_category == 4) {
                        Ext.getCmp('porter3combo').setValue(String(jsonData.defaultVal[i].name));
                    }
                    if (_category == 5) {
                        Ext.getCmp('assistantcombo').setValue(String(jsonData.defaultVal[i].name));
                    }
                    if (_category == 6) {
                        Ext.getCmp('tourAssignCombo').setValue(String(jsonData.defaultVal[i].name));
                    }
                }
            },
            failure: function (response, request) {
                Ext.MessageBox.alert('failure', response.responseText);
            },
            params: {
                selectedVCode: selVehicleCode,
                selectedFromDate: selFromDate.format('Y-m-d')
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I am using ExtJs 3.4. When I run the application my firebug console says:

```
NS_ERROR_MALFORMED_URI:


u.conn.open(w, t, true);
```

It doesn't call SetDefaultValues.java servlet. What's wrong with my code?

Please help me.

Thanx

Comment: most likely host, port, or projectName are not set when this call is made.  In firebug, under the Net tab you can see all the request being made from a page.  From here you can check the exact url being requested with this call.

Comment: It's not calling SetDefaultValues

Comment: There is no request for SetDefaultValues

Comment: But this worked before.

Comment: yes, with a malformed url the request will never make it to the server (SetDefaultValues in this case).  Use firebug's net tab to inspect the url.

Comment: Now it's ok.I put incorrect url